# genealogytree increase leveling or make content more readable

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, genealogytree

I am using `genealogytree` for a different purpose than genealogy because it produces good looking trees.

My problem is that when I have many nodes at the same level it becomes so small to read. I am trying to find a way to make my data look better. One way I thought of is to increase the level of some nodes but I did not figure out how to do it. I have also added an empty box (supposed to be a line) to try to fix it, but that did not work either.

My code:

```
        \documentclass{article}

        \usepackage{genealogytree}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \begin{document}





        \begin{landscape}
            \begin{figure}[b]
                \noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                    \begin{genealogypicture}[
                        processing=database,
                        database format=full,
                        info separators={\tcbline}{\tcbline}{}{},
                        category/.style={box={colback=red!20}}, % category
                        service/.style={box={colback=green!20}}, % a Service
                        realization/.style={box={colback=blue!20 }}, %Realization Technique
                        empty/.style={box={colback=white}}, %Realization Technique
                        edges={foreground={line width=1pt,black,->,},background={line width=2pt,white},}, %swing,
                        box={fit basedim=9pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,halign=center,valign=center,before upper=\parskip2pt,\gtrDBsex,{colback=gray!20}},%CATEGORY
                        %               node={ turn=right},
                        after tree={
                            \node [draw,black,fill=red!20,text height=1em] (a) at (current bounding box.north east) {Category};
                            \node [draw,black,fill=green!20,left=2mm of a] (b) {Service};
                            \node [draw,black,fill=blue!20,left=2mm of b] (c) { Technique};             
                        }
                        ]
                        child{
                            g{name={\textbf{CERT \\ Services}}}
                            child{
                                g[category]{name={\textbf{React Services}}, comment= {This is performed in the software}}
                                child{
                                    g[category]{name={\textbf{Linux Kernel Features}}, comment= {A feature in Linux kernel used to provide security}}

                                    child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{Incident Analysis}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                       
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }
                                    child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{Incident Response On-site}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                   
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }
                                    child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{Incident Response Support}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                   
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }
                                    child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{incident response coordination}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                  
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }                                               
                                }
                                child{
                                    g[category]{name={\textbf{Vulnerability Handling}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                        child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{Vulnerability Analysis}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                      
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                        }
                                        child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{Vulnerability Response}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                      
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                        }
                                        child {
                                        g[service]{name={\textbf{vulnerability Response Coordination}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                 
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                        }                           
                                }
                                child{
                                    g[category]{name={\textbf{Artifact Handling}}, comment= {Configuration automation}}
                                    child {
                                            g[service]{name={\textbf{Artifact Analysis}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                   
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }
                                    child {
                                            g[service]{name={\textbf{Artifact Response}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                   
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }
                                    child {
                                            g[service]{name={\textbf{Artifact Response Coordination}}, comment= {service explanation}}                              
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                        c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                    }   
                                }
                            }
                            child{
                                g[category]{name={\textbf{Proactive Services}}, comment= {This is performed in the hardware}}
                                child {
                                    g[empty]{name={\textbf{x}}}
                                    child{
                                        g[empty]{name={\textbf{x}}}
                                        child   {
                                            g[empty]{name={\textbf{x}}}
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                            child {
                                                g[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}                                         
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}
                                                c[realization]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {realization explanation}}                                     
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }                   
                                }
                            }
                            child{
                                g[category]{name={\textbf{Security Quality Management Services}}, comment= {This is performed in the hardware}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}}
                                c[service]{name={\textbf{xxx}}, comment= {service explanation}} 


                            }
                        }
                    \end{genealogypicture}
            }
            \end{figure}
        \end{landscape}
        \end{document}
```

output:

[image]

What i am trying to achieve: 
[image]

Any suggestions?

And are there better libraries to draw such tree/diagram?

EDIT: OP has a question regarding Forest solutions at [coverting a genealogy tree to forrest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403968/coverting-a-genealogy-tree-to-forrest).

Comment: If you don't want a genealogy tree, may be could try with [`forest`](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest)

Comment: Thank you, i read about it and converted it to forest. However, i am struggling with the style. I have added new topic here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403968/coverting-a-genealogy-tree-to-forrest

Comment: Do you still want this question? It seems really problematic that you're asking twice, so people may spend time on something here or there when you've already got a similar solution there or here.

Comment: Thank you cfr. However, I tried forest as an alternative to this issue which has not been solved yet.

Comment: Then can you clarify here? Right now, it asks for a solution either with `genealogytree` or with an alternative. `forest` was suggested in response, but you now have a separate question for that. So what's needed here? Not a `forest` solution, so what are the constraints on the alternatives? You should edit the question to avoid inadvertent duplication of efforts. If I'd realised the other question was basically a duplicate, I'd have answered here and voted to close the new question. But now it isn't clear what should be done. You say this is a different issue, but what is the issue exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer on the forest question. I have marked it as accepted answer because it shows that the tree can be converted. However, it does not satisfy my needs as replacement for this package for many downsides such as not being able to have similar size boxes while fitting it to size, and not being able to add comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Sari You can do that if you're prepared to scale it in the same way. But scaling diagrams with text is something to be considered only as a last resort in emergencies. Nothing in Forest stops you from implementing bad typographical decisions if you please. No idea what you mean about not being able to add a comment. You can add anything you can add in Ti*k*Z. But my point was that you should clarify this question to avoid duplication. It isn't at all clear to me what this question wants. Clarifying would be a lot more useful than a bounty.

Answer (score 6):

You can label parts of the diagram with "family" names via `id`, e.g.

```
child[id=VH]
```

and then use `options for family` to move the subtree, e.g.

```
  options for family={VH}{tikz={xshift=-8cm,yshift=-12cm},edge/xshift=-8cm,edge/yshift=-12cm}
```

Usually this will involve you labelling all `child` statements with the same label.  Below I move just one of your subtrees that I have labelled with `VH`.  You can use the same idea to move other parts, just use new names for the `id`.

Note I have set `name font` to `\bfseries` to avoid writing `\textbf` many times.  One can use other options to avoid much of the repetition of the coding in the diagram.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{figure}[b]
    \noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{genealogypicture}[
      processing=database,
      database format=full,
      info separators={\tcbline}{\tcbline}{}{},
      category/.style={box={colback=red!20},name font=\bfseries}, % category
      service/.style={box={colback=green!20},name font=\bfseries}, % a Service
      realization/.style={box={colback=blue!20},name font=\bfseries}, %Realization Technique
      empty/.style={box={colback=white}}, %Realization Technique
      edges={foreground={line width=1pt,black,->,},background={line width=2pt,white},}, %swing,
      box={fit basedim=9pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,halign=center,valign=center,before upper=\parskip2pt,\gtrDBsex,{colback=gray!20}},%CATEGORY
      % node={ turn=right},
      after tree={
      \node [draw,black,fill=red!20,text height=1em] (a) at (current bounding box.north east) {Category};
      \node [draw,black,fill=green!20,left=2mm of a] (b) {Service};
      \node [draw,black,fill=blue!20,left=2mm of b] (c) { Technique};
      },
      options for family={VH}{tikz={xshift=-8cm,yshift=-12cm},edge/xshift=-8cm,edge/yshift=-12cm}
      ]
      child{
      g{name={CERT \\ Services}}
      child{
      g[category]{name={React Services}, comment= {This is performed in the software}}
      child{
      g[category]{name={Linux Kernel Features}, comment= {A feature in Linux kernel used to provide security}}

      child {
      g[service]{name={Incident Analysis}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={Incident Response On-site}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={Incident Response Support}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={incident response coordination}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      }
      child[id=VH]{
      g[category]{name={Vulnerability Handling},
      comment= {service explanation}}
      child[id=VH] {
      g[service]{name={Vulnerability Analysis}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child[id=VH] {
      g[service]{name={Vulnerability Response}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child[id=VH] {
      g[service]{name={vulnerability Response Coordination}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      }
      child{
      g[category]{name={Artifact Handling}, comment= {Configuration automation}}
      child {
      g[service]{name={Artifact Analysis}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={Artifact Response}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={Artifact Response Coordination}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      }
      }
      child{
      g[category]{name={Proactive Services}, comment= {This is performed in the hardware}}
      child {
      g[empty]{name={x}}
      child{
      g[empty]{name={x}}
      child   {
      g[empty]{name={x}}
      child {
      g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
      child {
      g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
      }
        child {
        g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        }
        child {
        g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        }
        child {
        g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        }
        child {
        g[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        c[realization]{name={xxx}, comment= {realization explanation}}
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        child{
        g[category]{name={Security Quality Management Services}, comment= {This is performed in the hardware}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        c[service]{name={xxx}, comment= {service explanation}}
        }
        }
      \end{genealogypicture}
      }
    \end{figure}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be worth noting that scaling fonts is considered undesirable, even though it appears to be one of the OP's desiderata. ;)